# Make shapes semi-transparent, but not their text and borders

Tags: adobe-indesign, transparency

I want to draw the following image:

[image]

(This is from Wikipedia. I want to draw it in InDesign.)

The problem is that if I draw these circles by using Ellipse Tool and then set their opacity to 50 or 25%, this also affects text and borders. The text and borders should stay black; they should not be gray instead of black.

Is it possible without using two sets of frames: one set for background and another for text and borders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**

InDesign has separate transparency settings for the *Object* as a whole and its *Stroke*, *Fill* and *Text*.

These can be accessed using the *Effects* panel.

[image]